# Creating an OOP python EPOS system with a database

Tags: python, oop

Having some issues with classes and functions not being defined. Here is my code:

```
import hashlib

class LoginSystem():

  def __init__(self, Email, Username, Password, pass_check):
    self.Email = Email
    self.Username = Username
    self.Password = Password
    self.pass_check = pass_check

  def login(self, Username, Password):
    self.Username = input('Enter Username: ')
    self.Password = input("Enter Password: ")
    auth = Password.encode()
    auth_hash = hashlib.md5(auth).hexdigest()
    if Username == Username and Password == Password:
        print("Login Successful")

  def register(self, Email, Username, Password, pass_check):
    self.Email = input("Enter your email address: ")
    self.Username = input("Enter Username: ")
    self.Password = input("Enter Password: ")
    self.pass_check = input("Re-enter Password: ")

    if Password == pass_check:
        enc = pass_check.encode()
        hash1 = hashlib.md5(enc).hexdigest()
       
                    
    else:
      print("Passwords do not match")


while 1:
  print("********** Login System **********")
  print("1. Signup")
  print("2. Login")
  print("3. Exit")
  choice = int(input("Enter your choice"))
  if choice == 1:
    register()
  elif choice == 2:
    login()
  elif choice == 3:
    break
  else:
    print("Wrong choice! \n\n")

Getting the error:
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 43, in 
login()
NameError: name 'login' is not defined

```
when inputting login 

And this error when inputting for signup:
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 41, in 
register()
NameError: name 'register' is not defined

```
Tried to call the functions at different at different points but was still getting the same error.
```

Comment: Whts is your Python version?

Comment: I'm coding using replit so i'm not sure what version of python this is.

Comment: I think you do not understand classes and objects. You can read the [section](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) on them in the official tutorial, but I think you should read all of the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/index.html) first. In you case you get that error because you defined a method in a class but never instantiate it while trying to call a function you have never define.